# Bootcamp 2012 wireless driver

Tags: boot-camp

I'm trying to install windows server 2012 R2 trial to my Mac. Everything works except the wireless. I've already turn on the LAN wireless services feature but the server won't use the wireless device. Look like Bootcamp only provide wireless drivers for windows 8, not windows 2012 R2.

Is there a work around for this? I tried BCM-43XX drivers for windows 8.1 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was rectified by running the BootCamp driver setup again, *after* installing the Wireless LAN Service.  It would appear setup is different, depending on the presence of this service.

For the benefit of others, the process is:

- Install Windows Server 2012 using the BootCamp Assistant flash disk.
- Install **Wireless LAN Service** feature using the **Add Roles and Features Wizard**.
- Re-run the BootCamp drivers setup from your flash disk.  e.g. `e:\BootCamp\setup.exe`.

*[Source blog: Install Windows Server 2012...](http://oce-panda.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/install-windows-server-2012-r2-on.html)*